# Shiny - Dynamically generated actionButton within module not working with observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm creating a Shiny module which manipulates some raw data, providing the output in the form of a summary table. I'm rather new to shiny programming, apologies in advance for any newbie mistakes.

For the table, the aim is to create dynamic buttons (based on a filter variable). Depending on the filter selected, different number of buttons should appear, each with a unique function.

The function of each button is then to sort the table by a hidden column.
While i have been able to create the buttons, i have not been able to trigger the observeEvent function. Clicking on the buttons does not trigger any action. The code for creating the button is largely taken from the solution provided here: [Dynamically name the action buttons in R shiny from the values in Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679250/dynamically-name-the-action-buttons-in-r-shiny-from-the-values-in-data-frame)

I have tried following the solution here: [Shiny - Can dynamically generated buttons act as trigger for an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547786/shiny-can-dynamically-generated-buttons-act-as-trigger-for-an-event) as well as [R Shiny: Handle Action Buttons in Data Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739303/r-shiny-handle-action-buttons-in-data-table), but both solutions does not seem to work. I'm wondering if this is a namespace issue, but have no idea on how to resolve that either.

Here's a minimal, reproducible example that from the current module. I have removed a large portion of the code which should be irrelevant for the current problem. Nevertheless, do let me know if i have left out anything.

**Module UI**

```
SegmentationUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow(column(12, uiOutput(ns("sortbuttons")))), br(),
    fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput(ns("table1")), style = "width: 50%")          
  )
}

Segmentation <- function(input, output, session) {

  combinedtable <- reactiveVal({
    combinedtable <- data.table(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
               c(" 0.5", "0.8", "1.0", "0.2", "0.6", "0.5"),
               c(" 0.5", "0.8", "0.5", "0.4", "0.4", "0.5"),
               c(" 0.3", "0.1", "0.2", "0.6", "0.4", "0.3"),
               c(" 0.7", "0.8", "0.4", "0.3", "0.6", "0.3"),
               c(" 0.8", "0.9", "0.8", "0.5", "0.6", "0.7"),
               c(" 0.1", "0.4", "0.3", "0.2", "0.6", "0.8"),
               c(" 0.8", "0.8", "1.0", "1.2", "0.6", "0.5"),
               c(" 1.5", "0.8", "0.5", "0.4", "0.4", "1.5"),
               c(" 1.3", "1.1", "0.2", "0.9", "1.0", "0.3"),
               c(" 0.7", "0.8", "1.4", "0.3", "0.7", "1.3"),
               c(" 1.8", "1.9", "0.8", "0.9", "1.6", "0.9"),
               c(" 0.1", "0.4", "0.3", "1.0", "0.6", "0.8"))
  setnames(combinedtable, c(" ", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1new", "2new", "3new", "4new", "5new", "6new"))

  })

  unpivotedtable <- reactiveVal({
    unpivotedtable <- data.table(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                               c(" 0.5", "0.5", "0.3", "0.7", "0.8", "0.1"),
                               c(" 0.8", "0.8", "0.1", "0.8", "0.9", "0.4"),
                               c(" 1.0", "0.5", "0.2", "0.4", "0.8", "0.3"),
                               c(" 0.2", "0.4", "0.6", "0.3", "0.5", "0.2"),
                               c(" 0.6", "0.4", "0.4", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6"),
                               c(" 0.5", "0.5", "0.3", "0.3", "0.7", "0.8"))
  setnames(unpivotedtable, c("solution1", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))

  })

  obsList <- list()

  # Sort buttons
  output$sortbuttons <- renderUI({
    buttons <- lapply(1:nrow(unpivotedtable()), function(i)
    {
      buttonname <- paste0("button_", unpivotedtable()[i,1])
      # creates an observer only if it doesn't already exists
      if (is.null(obsList[[buttonname]])) {
        # make sure to use <<- to update global variable obsList
        obsList[[buttonname]] <<- observeEvent(input[[buttonname]], {
          cat("Button ", i, "\n")
          combinedtable() <- combinedtable()[order(paste(i,"new")),]
        })
      }
      actionButton(buttonname, paste(unpivotedtable()[i,1]))
    })

  })

  # Output table
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(combinedtable(), selection = "single", escape = FALSE,
              options = list(
                pageLength = 10,
                lengthMenu = c(10, 15, 20),
                initComplete = JS(
                  "function(settings, json) {",
                  "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
                  "}")
              )
    )

  )
}
```

**Ui Portion**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
# source("SegmentSummary.R")

# Define UI for dashboard
ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Segmentation Dashboard"),
  # Dashboard Sidebar
  dashboardSidebar( 
    # Sidebar Menu
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                # Menu for Segment Summary
                menuItem("Segment Summary", tabName = "SegmentSummary", icon = NULL)
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # Content for Segment Summary
      tabItem(tabName = "SegmentSummary", SegmentationUI(id = "Summary"))
    )
  )
)
)
```

**Server Portion**

```
# Define server logic 
ShinyServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Call Module for Segment Summary
  callModule(Segmentation, "Summary")
}
```

**Run App**

```
shinyApp(ui, ShinyServer)
```

The sort function itself that i have included may not be correct in itself as i have just produced it based on my current understanding of data table sorting. Currently i have tried simpler observeEvent effect such as print("hi") and renderText, but clicking the buttons doesnt seem to have any impact. I'll be most open to any suggestions if the sort function itself is mistakened.

Here's a brief data structure of the tables that are used in the relevant code.

```
Unpivoted Table
Solution1   A       B       C
1           0.50    1.93    0.62
2           0.85    1.58    0.53
3           0.45    1.69    0.82
4           1.42    0.85    0.45
5           0.52    1.40    0.98
6           0.36    0.39    1.95

Combined Table
    1       2       3       4       5       6       1new    2new    3new    4new    5new    6new
A   0.50    0.85    0.45    1.42    0.52    0.36    0.50    0.06    1.20    0.64    1.96    0.31
B   1.93    1.58    1.69    0.85    1.40    0.39    0.40    1.54    1.54    1.69    1.63    0.18
C   0.62    0.53    0.82    0.45    0.98    1.95    0.30    1.56    0.74    0.16    1.67    1.71
```

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi stormshadow and welcome to SO. Please make sure your min reprex actually runs and fulfils the criteria here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Eli i have updated the code to include the ui & server portion of the code - not sure if thats what you meant by considering it as a minimal reproducible example. I have left out the code for the tables as they are generated from a separate data set. Do let me know if i'm still lacking something. Thanks!

Comment: I am still having trouble running your code on my side. The idea of a min reprex is that an external party can just copy and run your code and get to your problem quickly. Ideally you should even add dummy data in a way that it gets created e.g. `unpivotedtable <- data.frame(...)` but that part I can work around.

Comment: Hi Eli, apologies for that. I didnt create the tables as they are a result of an extensive conversion from the raw data. Regardless, i have created some dummydata as you suggested. I tested it out and the code should work now. Thanks!

Comment: I have made some edits to properly make it a min reprex. However my issue now is `obsList <- list()` means `obsList` is an empty list and therefore `obsList[[buttonname]]` doesn't mean anything. I think you need to look into using reactiveValues/reactiveVal. You should never really need the global operator <<- in a shiny app. It's considered bad practice. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/reactiveValues.html and https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.1.0/reactiveVal.html

Comment: I took followed the code here quite closely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547786/shiny-can-dynamically-generated-buttons-act-as-trigger-for-an-event. My understanding of the rationale of the global operator is because observeEvent has isolate within itself, so global is required to return the output. Am i mistaken? Nevertheless, i'm more than open to any alternative suggestions.

Comment: I see. That part is working, apologies

Comment: I don't have further time now but my suggestion is to try and get the app to work without the module i.e. run `shinyApp(SegmentationUI, Segmentation)` after removing `ns <- NS(id)` and any `ns` in the ui. Get that working first then make it a module if you haven't done so already.